# Is usage of \ell instead of l in math mode best practice?

Tags: fonts, best-practices

Is usage of `\ell` instead of `l` in math mode best practice?

Comment: In my opinion using `\ell` is better because it's easier to distinguish it from the digit _1._ Mind you, this is more a question about typography than about LaTeX.

Comment: But ins't LaTeX also about typesetting? But moderators may feel free to delete my question if it doesn't fit at all ...

Comment: IMO the question is valid but (as I wrote) more about typography than about LaTeX.

Comment: I'm thinking too that this is not about TeX. In my opinion `\ell` should never be used: in good printing the math italic "l" is easily distinguishable from other symbols.

Comment: @ergeg But there are use cases when a specific symbol is common in a physics or mathematics group or theory. The symbol produced by `\ell` is common in statistical mechanics, for example, where the non-usage of it could leed to confusion in the community. Another example would be the distinction between the angular momentum in classical (`l`) and quantum mechanics (`\ell`), which is often made by choosing different symbols for the same letter.

Answer (score 11):

This depends on the context and font used. If there is no possibility to confuse `l` and `I` or `1`, than you can safely use `l`. If there is, you might want to change to `\ell`, but you should be aware, that

- it might differ from the other gylphs in style too much.
- it might conflict with international standards, for example in the case of the [litre symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litre#Symbol).

If you use it for high-school students or persons not accustumed to the symbols, `\ell` is preferable as the obvious distinction to `1` and `I` is more important. For example, I always use `\ell` as the symbol for litre in tests and training sheets for my high school students, because they still have problems reading `$V \text{in} \si{\litre}$` correctly.

Comment: Don't use `\ell` as the symbol for liters; either "l" or "L". See http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/outside.html where you find "Neither a lowercase script letter l nor an uppercase script letter L are approved symbols for the liter".

Comment: How are your students "not accustomed to the liter symbol"? Don't they see it everyday on bottles and such?

Comment: @T.Verron: No, they don't in general, because they don't walk around the world with open eyes. They are children, who have to learn this.

Comment: @egreg: High school students don't know that there might be a semantic difference between script letters and non script letters. Both are simply glyph variants to them. So they are not interpreting this glyph as "script l which must be something different than non script l".

Comment: Writing by hand is different from typesetting. And if students don't know something, teach them. :)

Comment: @egreg: I do, but I know pedagogics. Teaching them about volumina and the unit litre is my aim. Teaching them about semantic differences of different math alphabets is not. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_inhibition for my further reasoning.

Comment: If `\ell` can/should be used for liters also depends on the country, you are in. In German-speaking countries the `\ell` is commonly used for liters in all places, while in English speaking countries it's not.

Comment: @Toscho : noone suggests you explain the difference between the glyphs, just that you typeset properly the character so that they get used to seeing it correctly written.

Comment: @FooBar : The international unit system exists for a good reason. To take a more extreme example, in some countries, 'm' is a common abbreviation for 'mile' (think for example 'mph'), that doesn't mean this habbit shouldn't disappear.

Comment: @T.Verron In Germany there are also other norms that have to be used by law. They are mostly compatible to the SI, but in some details they differ (`\cdot` instead of `\times`: `2 \cdot 10^5` instead of `2 \times 10^5`). For liter several symbols are officially (`l`, `L` and `\ell`) allowed, but `\ell` is the most common from historical reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for educational uses outside of professional math, but as far as I know, the *only* time `\ell` is used to mean something specific is to denote a prime other than `p` in certain parts of number theory (typically arithmetic geometry).  But this convention is strong enough that it's got a similar force as the use of `e` or `\pi` to those who know.  I actually think it's a bad idea to use it as a variable, for example an alternate index of summation when `k` and `m` are also used as indices, because it is visually inconsistent with them.  I don't think you need to worry about it being confused with `1` or `I`; TeX is not AOL and you can't alias someone's username with this trick in it :)  More seriously, Computer Modern is a serif font and they all look different.  Now, if you were writing a Beamer presentation you might want to cut down on the vertical-line characters, since its default font is sans; alternatively, you might switch it to using CM, which is nicer.

Comment: The default font in beamer is the sans-serif version of CM, so you probably mean "switch to using roman". Also, for interested people, there is a thorough discussion about fonts and font families in both text body and math, in the beamer manual.

Comment: No, `\ell` is also used to denote sequence spaces and as such a fundamental object it appears in any book on Hilbert spaces, functional analysis, real analysis.

Answer (score 1):

`\ell` is baked into mathematics to denote sequence spaces, like `\ell^2` (read as "little ell two") is the space of square summable sequences with which every Hilbert space is isomorphic, so it is the quintessential Hilbert space to study. In a paper where such spaces are used, do not use `\ell` for anything else. Otherwise, it's fine to use it, and yes, there is a problem using the letter `l` because of possible confusion with `1` in text, but prepending the letter with the name of the object can make `l` ok to use, like in `The functional $l$ is extended...`